# Cannot get AutoCompleteTextView to show with other components

Tags: java, android, google-maps, autocompletetextview

I am trying to build a simple Android app one of whose activities will have a Google Places `AutoCompleteTextView` along with a `Button` and several other components.  However, it seems to be the case that the `AutoCompleteTextView` component does not want to play friendly with anything else.  Currently, I can only get one (the `AutoCompleteTextView` component) or the others rendering at a time.  Here are the relevant portions of my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Please enter your place" >
        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current Date (M-D-YYYY): "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dpResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**GooglePlacesAutocompleteActivity.java**

```
public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    // class fields are here ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setCurrentDateOnView();    // sets up the date picker
        addListenerOnButton();     // adds a listener to a Button

        // next three lines configure the Google Place autocomplete
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    // more methods...
}
```

If you need more information to render an answer here, please feel free to ask me and I will post as soon as I can.

Comment: orientation is horizontal and you have width : match_parent

Comment: Facepalm time.  I am a beginner to Android, having spent my youth doing J2EE and Core Java.  Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You have a problem of orientation in your LinearLayout. I guess you want your AutocompleteTextView in top of the rest. If that is the case you should probably add a nested LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <AutoCompleteTextView
          android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:ems="10"
          android:text="Please enter your place" >
          <requestFocus />
      </AutoCompleteTextView>

      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

          [your other items]

     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If this is not what you are looking for just change match_parent to wrap_content for thw width of your AutocompleteTextView.